# How to use Trim in sql with FOR JSON

Tags: sql, mysql-json

I want so select a column and wants to trim it with FOR JSON.

```
SELECT LOWER(LTRIM(RTRIM(column_name))) AS a FROM table_name FOR JSON
```

will TRIM work along with FOR JSON ?

If not what is alternative for it?.

Comment: Tip: Simplify as `TRIM(column_nam)`.

Comment: Error : TRIM is not recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Isn't `FOR JSON [PATH/AUTO]` SQL server? (Although you have mysql tagged)